# Is my DSL good idea to replace builder pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to build a set of [builders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for generating test data. On one side I want my builders API to be natural to use for my teammates. On the other side I'm great fun of creating [DSLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), because it eliminates writing the same boilerplate code and let you read the code as English sentences.

However, I found those requirements quite incompatible. I've shown my builders to my teammate and what was intuitive to me, was not for him. He would need to learn my DSL.

How would you improve my design decisions in Builder pattern?

**Decision #1: Long domain names vs. new short names**

I started with traditional `withX()` methods for setting field *X*. For *X* I used names that are well known in our domain and commonly used in the rest of implementation.

```
Flight.Builder.create()
   .withOrigin(Airport.LAX) 
   .withDestination(Airport.JFK)
   .build();
```

Then I thought this takes too much space, so I used method names that are shorter but uncommon in the rest of the implementation.

```
Flight.Builder.create()
   .from(Airport.JFK)
   .to(Airport.LAX)
   .build();
```

Another programmer prefered traditional names from the domain: origin, destination.

**Decision #2: Clear method names vs. duplicate methods with type-overloading**

Another weak point I found was redundancy of some information. For instance, in the following code:

```
Flight.Builder.create()
  .withPassenger(Passenger.ADULT) // that's a template
  .withPassenger(Passenger.Builder.create().withName("KENNEDDY"))
  .withStatus(Status.CANCELLED)
  .build();
```

the redundancy is in passenger-passenger, and in status-status. So I removed redudant words from method names and used type-overloading.

```
Flight.Builder.create()
  .with(Passenger.ADULT)
  .with(Passenger.Builder.create().withName("KENNEDDY"))
  .with(Status.CANCELLED)
  .build();
```

The programmer who knows data model underlying this builder and was used to more traditional builder pattern, was confused with my approach.

**Decision #3: Changing words order and delegating builder creation**

Then I found builder creation kind of boilerplate code that makes it harder to read:

```
Flight.Builder.create()
   .withPassenger(Passenger.Builder.create().withName("KENNEDDY"))
   .build();
```

I shortened those constructs. I also found this incompatible with English words order in sentence, where you don't say "what.build()", but "build(what)". Here's the result.

```
build(flight()
  .withPassenger(passenger().withName("KENNEDDY")));
```

How would you improve my design decisions?

Comment: Is my question too loooong or title unclear? Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: The question and the title seem fine although it might fit better to Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few, rather subjective thoughts:

**Decision #1:**

Here you have a flight builder. Which group of sentences looks more natural from the following?

- *a flight builder with origin*
- *a flight builder with destination*

or

- *a flight builder from*
- *a flight builder to*

The first two looks better for me.

Furthermore, if origin and destination are in your domain you should use them. Using synonyms could be confusing.

**Decision #2:**

I may be worth to note that if you have more than one field with the same type (strings and ints are common) it would not work. Having builders in the same application and one half of them is using `with()` while the other half is using `withX()` is also confusing.

**Decision #3:**

The `passenger().withName("KENNEDDY")` statements make me think about where the passenger instance comes from. A database or maybe a cache? I think a `create` word somewhere would make it obvious that it's a new instance and it would be helpful for readers although renaming `passenger()` to `createPassenger()` does not seem natural in this code too.

Comment: Regarding passenger creation. In our business domain passenger instances are not shared across flight. Instead, they are created for each flight separately, so `createPassenger()` or `createPax()` would be more clear. (pax is common synonym here)